# Duda con Enrutamiento de un archivo en aplicación de escritorio con windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

tengo un proyecto en Windows Forms con lenguaje C#, el cual me genera unas cartas a partir de una plantilla en word.

El asunto es que todo me funciona correctamente pero necesito pasar este desarrollo a ambiente de producción, y al pasarlo a ambiente de producción obviamente en el pc que se instale ya no va a encontrar ese enrutamiento:

A continuación les muestro como tengo definido el enrutamiento:

```
                var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

                document = application.Documents.Add(Template: @"D:\Proyectos\chc_deuda\chc_deuda\resources\Document\PEVI-cartaPreadj.docx");
```

Mi pregunta sería como hago para que ese enrutamiento quede desde \resources\Document\PEVI-cartaPreadj.docx y no pasando toda la ruta desde el disco D:\,

O en donde y como debería pasar estos archivos para que al momento de sacarlo a producción me los seleccione desde una carpeta generica que entienda cualquier pc en el que se instale.

Cuando generó el archivo .exe lo hago desde visual studio en la opción compilar y luego accionó la opción publicar. Ya que trabajo para una empresa y me dijeron que el .exe lo generará de esa maner.

Agradecería mucho que alguíen me pueda ayudar con esto

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si pones el `docx` junto al `.exe` podrias usar

```
string rutaDoc = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "PEVI-cartaPreadj.docx");
document = application.Documents.Add(Template: rutaDoc);
```

Usando el [Application.StartupPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath?view=netframework-4.5) obtienes la ruta donde esta la aplicacion y si ubiscaste el documento alli mismo lo podra acceder

Comment: Muchas Gracias Leandro Tuttini esa fue la solución

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción aparte de la de Leandro es colocar la ruta del archivo en el archivo de configuración de la aplicación, de esta forma no quedas amarrado a una ruta específica.

Por ejemplo, en tu archivo de configuración (App.Config) puedes colocar esto;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="rutaDocumento" value="D:\Proyectos\chc_deuda\chc_deuda\resources\Document\PEVI-cartaPreadj.docx" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Y en tu código:

```
try
{
    string rutaDoc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rutaDocumento"];
}
catch(ConfigurationErrorsException)
{
    // si entra aquí es que no está establecida la entrada en el archivo config
}
```

De esta forma, simplemente editas el archivo de configuración para cambiar la ruta, es mas, hasta puedes agregar una opción en tu aplicación donde le permites al usuario configurar la ruta donde está guardado el documento.

```
var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
if (configFile.AppSettings["rutaDocumento"] == null)
{
    configFile.Add("rutaDocumento", "nueva ruta");
}
else
{
    configFile.AppSettings["rutaDocumento"].Value = "nueva ruta";
}
```